# How can I make Bootstrap 5 grids responsive to smartphones?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a projects section part of my portfolio. I alternate between description on left/image on right to image on left/description on right. I have been painstakingly trying to make this responsive, but I cannot think of what to do to fix this. I want the image on top and the text below on every project when viewed on a smartphone.

This is the HTML for the projects section:

```
<section id="projects">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row projects">
              <h1>My Projects</h1>
            <div class="col project-desc-left">
              <h2>Tindog</h2>
                <p>An landing page for the Tindog app. A twist on a typical dating app. Created with Bootstrap 5 and HTML/CSS utilizing Bootstrap grids.</p>
                <i class="fab fa-html5"></i> <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i> <i class="fab fa-bootstrap"></i><br>
                <a class="btn button primary-button mr-4 live-site-btn" href="https://kiannaamaya.github.io/TinDog-WebDevBootcamp/" role="button" target="_blank">Live Site</a>
                <a class="btn button secondary-button mr-4 github-btn" href="https://github.com/kiannaamaya/TinDog-WebDevBootcamp" role="button" target="_blank">Github Repo</a>            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-6 col-sm-12 project-img-right">
              <img class="project-img" src="assets/tindog.png"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row projects">
            <div class="col">
              <img class="project-img" src="assets/nftcard.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col project-desc-right">
              <h2>NFT Preview Card</h2>
                <p>An preview card page created with HTML/CSS.</p>
                <i class="fab fa-html5"></i> <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i> <br>
                <a class="btn button primary-button mr-4 live-site-btn" href="https://kiannaamaya.github.io/nft-preview-card-component-main/" role="button" target="_blank">Live Site</a>
          <a class="btn button secondary-button mr-4 github-btn" href="https://github.com/kiannaamaya/nft-preview-card-component-main" role="button" target="_blank">Github Repo</a>            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row projects">
            <div class="col project-desc-left">
              <h2>3-Card Column</h2>
                <p>A preview card of vehicle options created with HTML/CSS.</p>
                <i class="fab fa-html5"></i> <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i> </i><br>
                <a class="btn button primary-button mr-4 live-site-btn" href="https://kiannaamaya.github.io/3-column-preview-card-component-main/" role="button" target="_blank">Live Site</a>
                <a class="btn button secondary-button mr-4 github-btn" href="https://github.com/kiannaamaya/3-column-preview-card-component-main" role="button" target="_blank">Github Repo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col project-img-right">
              <img class="project-img" src="assets/3colcard.png"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I used Bootstrap 5 and I tried to use col-xs-12 but it didn't look right and it also completely messed up the desktop view. The laptop view looks exactly how I want it to look, it's just every other sizing that it completely wrong.

This is the CSS:

```
/* Projects */
    
    #projects {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #projects h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .projects {
        margin-left: 0;
        
    }

    .project-img{
        width: 300px;
    }
    
    .project-desc-left {
        margin: 5rem;
        width: 320px;
    }
    
    .project-desc-right {
        
    }
}
```

I have been trying to tweak the code for days, but I have barely made any progress.

[This is the laptop view of the projects section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqY2c.png)

[This is the mobile view of the projects section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9zEO.png)

Comment: You can add media queries for mobile.  .project-desc-left class is taking too much margin for mobile.

Comment: Look up the basics of bootstrap grid, your are using it wrong. If you use cols then don't set a custom width on them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using Bootstrap 5 `Column Ordering` without adding any extra CSS. You can add these classes to your `Col`'s and they will appear on the page in the order given no matter their physical place in your HTML.

General useage.

```
.order-1
.order-2
.order-3
.order-4
.order-5
```

Ordering according to screen size. In this exammple, the Column will show 1st on SM screens, it will show second on MD screens and third on LG screens.

```
.order-sm-1
.order-md-2
.order-lg-3 etc etc etc
```

You can also specify items to be `unordered` or `ordered-first` and `ordered-last`. Here are the docs for everything here....

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#order-classes